# How do I return a nonflat numpy array selecting elements given a set of conditions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements, slice

I have a multidimensional array, say of shape (4, 3) that looks like

```
a = np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(10,11,12)])
```

If I have a list of fixed conditions

```
conditions = [True, False, False, True]
```

How can I return the list

```
array([(1,2,3),(10,11,12)])
```

Using `np.extract` returns

```
>>> np.extract(conditions, a)
array([1, 4])
```

which only returns the first element along each nested array, as opposed to the array itself. I wasn't sure if or how I could do this with `np.where`. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's define you variables:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(10,11,12)])
>>> conditions = [True, False, False, True]
```

Now, let's select the elements that you want:

```
>>> a[np.array(conditions)]
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

#### Aside

Note that the simpler `a[conditions]` has some ambiguity:

```
>>> a[conditions]
-c:1: FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a boolean array index
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

As you can see, `conditions` are treated here as (integer-like) index values which is not what we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple list slicing and `np.where` It's more or less made specifically for this situation..

```
>>> a[np.where(conditions)]
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
```

Comment: On a quick test on large array, surprisingly it's slightly  faster than converting to array and boolean indexing!